# Find difference between two timestamps

Tags: java, date, time

I want to find differences between given timestamp and current system time.

My code,

```
Long timeStamp=1500462813;  
long diff=(timeStamp*1000L) - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

diff i am getting is not what I am expacting.

Ex. 
(1500462813*1000)-1500290013000=172800000

this is of date  6/24/1975, 5:30:00 AM 
I am expecting  7/19/2017, 4:43:33PM .

want to find the difference between current system time and given time stamp, to run timer for the remaining time.

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: The difference between two timestamps isn't a date. It's... a difference.

Comment: how can find a difference in timestamp?

Comment: @RahulDevanavar First you should tell us what you mean by "difference in timestamp". How would a difference between two timestamps ever relate to a date in the future?

Comment: I want to find the difference between current system time and given time stamp, to run timer for the remaining time.

Comment: @RahulDevanavar You get difference in milliseconds `172800000`. What's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to convert to a date? It's a duration of time, not a point in time, so it would make sense if it's not valid. And how would you use a date with a timer? Why not just use the resulting `long` directly?

Comment: If you subtract from `1500462813000` (19 July) current date `1500290013000` (17 July) you'll get 2 days. `172800000` is exactly 2 days in milliseconds (`2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`). How can you get the date from it? And why do you need a date for timer?

Comment: @RahulDevanavar: Again: The difference between two timestamps **is not** a date. **it never will be a date**. The difference between those two timestamps is 172800000 miliseconds. If in your head those miliseconds somehow relate to a date, then **please tell us how**. Because we have no idea what idea you have that somehow converts a difference in miliseconds to a date (in the future non the less).

Comment: Thanks, I got issue.

Comment: You may want to check out the `Duration` class (it’s in the `java.time` package, or the `org.threeten.bp` package if you are using Java 6 or 7 and ThreeTen Backport).

Comment: this may helps https://gist.github.com/Ashusolanki/fed3b6a680092985ac0ab93ed70fcd7c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public static long getDateDiff(long timeUpdate, long timeNow, TimeUnit timeUnit)
{
    long diffInMillies = Math.abs(timeNow - timeUpdate);
    return timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

It gives you the difference of whatever unit (days, years, ...).

```
long timestamp1 = 1500462813000;
long timestamp2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long diffInDays = getDateDiff(timestamp1, timestamp2, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Comment: This Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: You are right - I edited my answer - it also works without Date. Only the timestamp is needed.

Answer (score 5):

First I see that you are using the primitive type `long` and the class `Long`. It's not a good idea. If you do not have really good reasons to use the class better use just `long`.

You are initialising the class `Long` with an integer:

```
Long timeStamp=1500462813;
```

That's actually a compiler error. So your code could not be compiled.

If I understood correct your question you want the remaining time to a date. You are actually getting it. In milliseconds. Your result is the time that remains to your timestamp date.

This result isn't a `Date` on its own. It is just the milliseconds to your desired date.

Comment: how to find date

Comment: What date do you want to get? You wanted the difference. You have it. The difference could not be interpreted as a Date.

Comment: Maybe you could explain more about youre problem. Write us what you want to do, the purpouse. As i understood you are doing evrything correct. Youre just do not understood what you got.

Comment: Please read some advises for question asking. You are asking very bad. It should be possible to us understand what zthe problem is. Give more information what you did and what did not worked and what do you want to have. So precise as possible (but without usless information). Question asking is a culture on its own.

Comment: Yes, I got sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
long diff= System.currentTimeMillis() - givenTimeStamp;
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.  How do you know this really answers the question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you still not understood question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find the difference like this

```
long timeStamp=System.currentTimeMillis();  
long diff=(timeStamp-1500462813000);
```

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will always greater than your current